# Curl function to get zone from pointhq.com

Tags: php, curl

curl -u "user@example.com:f9eca287-5346-1cc7-8529-68eb9db7cd5e" -H 'Accept: application/json' -H "Content-type: application/json" https://pointhq.com/zones

How can I call this in php

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using basic authentication and you can use following;

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pointhq.com/zones"); 
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-type: application/json')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user@example.com:f9eca287-5346-1cc7-8529-68eb9db7cd5e");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```

For more detail refer [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)